# Не могу обратиться к классу в c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Написал программу каталогизатор, прописывал все прямо в теле обработчиков событий. Но препод наругал, сказал, что все должно быть красиво, и сказал переделать с использованием классов. Он хочет чтобы обработчики обращались к классам. Кнопка удалить не работает, хотя программа запускается. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я делаю не так. Вот код:
Сам класс

```
public static class Delete
{
    public static void del()
    {    
        ListBox listBox1 = new ListBox();
        TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox();
        listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox1.Clear();
    }
}
```

А вот то место, где идет обращение к нему

```
public void deleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // удаляет выбранный элемент из списка
    Delete.del();
}
```

Comment: Скорее всего вы неправильно поняли слова вашего преподавателя. Вы не могли бы показать полный код?

Comment: Что за лажа в методе `del`? Создаются новые ListBox и TextBox и что-то в них очищается.

Comment: @FoggyFinder залил на облако весь проект, вот ссыль
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/87MA/BXeQPa4UV

Comment: @AntonShchyrov я только начал разбираться в программировании... Можете поподробнее объяснить, что не так? Как нужно было сделать, и почему

Comment: @AntonShchyrov без строчек
    ListBox listBox1 = new ListBox();
TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox(); компилятор ругается. Пишет, что элементов в остальных строках не существует в данном контексте

Comment: @PavelDorosh Правильно пишет. Это поля формы, о которой класс `Delete` ничего не знает

Comment: @FoggyFinder Спасибо большое вам

Comment: @FoggyFinder Проблема уже решена, спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Твой класс ничего не знает об элементах формы и поэтому он не работает!

Ты зачем-то внутри своего класса создаешь новые объекты, которые никак не связаны с тем, что ты видишь на форме.

Что бы все работало, ты должен сделать метод, который принимает объекты ListBox и TextBox и тогда, класс будет работать с реальными объктами на форме.

**UPD**

```
public static class Delete
{
    public static void del(ListBox listBox1,TextBox textBox1)//добавляешь аргументы в метод
    {    
        listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox1.Clear();
    }
}
```

И передавай элементы:

```
public void deleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // удаляет выбранный элемент из списка
    Delete.del(listBox1,textBox1);
}
```

Comment: можно пожалуйста поподробнее. Просто без этих первых двух строчек компилятор ругается. Пишет, что элементов не существует в данном контексте, или как то так...

Comment: @PavelDorosh, ругается он правильно, так как , как я уже сказал, твой класс не знает ничего о них. Передавай их через аргумента.

Comment: Спасибо большое, вы очень помогли!!

Answer (score 0):

```
public void deleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (listBox1.SelectedItem != -1)
    listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
  textBox1.Clear();
}
```

Comment: я так понял, что первая строка в теле обработчика - проверка, выбран ли элемент. О том, что идет дальше, мне известно. Реально ли сделать это через обращение к классу? Чтобы тело обработчика было прописано в другом классе, а в обработчике события было только обращение к тому классу.

Comment: @PavelDorosh Что Вам даст работа с другим классом? Вам нужно работать с конкретными объектами о которых другой класс ничего не знает. Ну можете создать класс, ему передать два объекта формы и пусть он вызывает эти три строчки. Но это **бред**

Comment: да, я понимаю, что это бредятина, но у нас тема это работа с классами. Если вы посмотрите код, который я скинул выше, вы увидите, что остальные кнопки с классами не работают(изначально я принес такой проект). Но мне сказали сделать с классами. Я создал класс для кнопки Delete, передал все что нужно, программа запускается, но не работает кнопка. Вот я и спрашиваю, что у меня в коде не так?